# How to fix MUI inputfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Today I had problem with inputfield using mui, Im going to upload screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHCQn.png)

I tried several things, but nothing happened. Documentation did not help aswell. I could not find solution , I use chrome browser.

Here is the code ,  I read mui documentation , even used ready examples , but inputfield is rendered like in the screenshot above.

```js
div className='account'>
      <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ marginTop: '120px' }}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Typography variant="h4">
            Welcome {''} 
            <Typography variant="inherit" component="span" style={{ color: '#50dfeb' }}>
              {userData && userData.custom_claims ? userData.custom_claims.global_name : (userData ? userData.full_name : 'Guest')}
            </Typography>
            , here you can edit your profile information.
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
          <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>
              <Avatar
                alt="User"
                src={userData && userData.avatar_url}
                sx={{ width: 78, height: 76 }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleOpen}>
                Connect LOL account
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Connect LOL Account</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} alignItems="center">
            <PillField
              label="Game Name"
              fullWidth
              value={gameName}
              onChange={(e) => setGameName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <Select
                value={region}
                onChange={(e) => setRegion(e.target.value)}
                displayEmpty
              >
                <MenuItem value="" disabled>Select region</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="EUNE">EUNE</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="EUW">EUW</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="NA">NA</MenuItem>
                {/* Add more regions as needed */}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </Stack>
          <TextField
            label="Tag Line"
            fullWidth
            value={tagLine}
            onChange={(e) => setTagLine(e.target.value)}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleConnect} color="primary">Connect</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum viable example with code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example